# Responsive two to three column layout in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve a particular flex/grid responsive behavior that grows from two to three columns, expanding only two containers. I illustrated the desired results below. I was able to manage the two-column stage. However, I don't know how to expand this to three columns using css flex-box.

*I chose flex-box as this got me closest to where I need to get. However, the solution must by no means be limited to flex-box.*

[image]

Situation:

- 5 containers in total.
- 3 have a fixed but individual height, 2 should grow in their hight dimension.
- The containers are organized in 2 columns for small screens and 3 columns for large screens as shown on the sketch.
- Between the 2 and 3 column stages and beyond the three column stage, the width of all 5 containers should equal 50% (33% respectively) of the parent element's width.

```js
let wf = 0.5;
let wm = 500;

function simulateWidthUpdate() {
  const g = document.getElementById('grid')
  wf = wf == 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
  g.style.width = parseInt(wf * wm) + 'px';
}
```

```css
button {
 margin: 10px 0;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #233C3C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#item-c,
#item-d {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#item-a {
   height: 20px;
}


#item-b {
   height: 40px;
}

#item-e {
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="simulateWidthUpdate()">Alternate Width</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div class="item" id="item-a">A</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-c">B</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-e">C</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-b">D</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-d">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the order of individual divs matter? They has to be in these places like in the screenshot you showed?

Comment: @luknij yes, the order matters; A, B and E have a fixed height whilst C and D should take the maximum height available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider explicitly organizing the columns as separate elements. Then use JavaScript to organize the elements as per your wireframes when `simulateWidthUpdate()` runs.

```js
let wf = 0.5;
let wm = 500;

const a = document.getElementById('item-a');
const b = document.getElementById('item-b');
const c = document.getElementById('item-c');
const d = document.getElementById('item-d');

function simulateWidthUpdate() {
  const g = document.getElementById('grid')
  wf = wf == 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
  g.style.width = parseInt(wf * wm) + 'px';
  
  if (wf === 1) {
    a.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', b);
    
    const newColumn = document.createElement('div');
    newColumn.className = 'column';
    newColumn.appendChild(c);
    document.querySelector('.column').insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newColumn);
  } else {
    d.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', b);
    a.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', c);
    document.querySelectorAll('.column')[1].remove();
  }
}
```

```css
button {
 margin: 10px 0;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}  

.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #233C3C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#item-c,
#item-d {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#item-a {
   height: 20px;
}


#item-b {
   height: 40px;
}

#item-e {
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="simulateWidthUpdate()">Alternate Width</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item" id="item-a">A</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-c">C</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-e">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item" id="item-b">B</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-d">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Pure CSS

You could use container queries and CSS grid:

```js
let wf = 0.5;
let wm = 500;

function simulateWidthUpdate() {
  const g = document.getElementById('grid')
  wf = wf == 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
  g.style.width = parseInt(wf * wm) + 'px';
}
```

```css
button {
 margin: 10px 0;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "a b" 40px
    "c b" 10px
    "c d" minmax(200px, 1fr)
    "e d" 70px;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@container (width > 400px) {
  .inner {
    grid-template:
      "a c d" max-content
      "b c d" max-content
      "e c d" max-content
      "x c d" 1fr;
  }
}

.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #233C3C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#item-c,
#item-d {
  min-height: 200px;
}

#item-a {
   height: 20px;
   grid-area: a;
}


#item-b {
   height: 40px;
   grid-area: b;
}

#item-c {
   grid-area: c;
}

#item-d {
   grid-area: d;
}

#item-e {
   height: 50px;
   grid-area: e;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="simulateWidthUpdate()">Alternate Width</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item" id="item-a">A</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-b">B</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-c">C</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-d">D</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-e">E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use a `style` attribute selector instead of container queries:

```js
let wf = 0.5;
let wm = 500;

function simulateWidthUpdate() {
  const g = document.getElementById('grid')
  wf = wf == 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
  g.style.width = parseInt(wf * wm) + 'px';
}
```

```css
button {
 margin: 10px 0;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "a b" 40px
    "c b" 10px
    "c d" minmax(200px, 1fr)
    "e d" 70px;
  gap: 10px;
}

#grid[style*="500px"] {
  grid-template:
    "a c d" max-content
    "b c d" max-content
    "e c d" max-content
    "x c d" 1fr;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #233C3C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#item-c,
#item-d {
  min-height: 200px;
}

#item-a {
   height: 20px;
   grid-area: a;
}


#item-b {
   height: 40px;
   grid-area: b;
}

#item-c {
   grid-area: c;
}

#item-d {
   grid-area: d;
}

#item-e {
   height: 50px;
   grid-area: e;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="simulateWidthUpdate()">Alternate Width</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div class="item" id="item-a">A</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-b">B</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-c">C</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-d">D</div>
  <div class="item" id="item-e">E</div>
</div>
```

Or a "brute-force" approach similar to the first JavaScript solution, where we duplicate the DOM for both instances and switch between them using a `style` attribute selector or container query:

```js
let wf = 0.5;
let wm = 500;

function simulateWidthUpdate() {
  const g = document.getElementById('grid')
  wf = wf == 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
  g.style.width = parseInt(wf * wm) + 'px';
}
```

```css
button {
 margin: 10px 0;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}  

.item {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #233C3C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#item-c,
#item-d {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#item-a {
   height: 20px;
}


#item-b {
   height: 40px;
}

#item-e {
   height: 50px;
}

@container (width >= 500px) {
  .wide-hide {
    display: none;
  }
}

@container (width < 500px) {
  .wide-show {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="simulateWidthUpdate()">Alternate Width</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item" id="item-a">A</div>
    <div class="item wide-show" id="item-b">B</div>
    <div class="item wide-hide" id="item-c">C</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-e">E</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column wide-show">
    <div class="item" id="item-c">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item wide-hide" id="item-b">B</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-d">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I was looking for a pure CSS approach (the JS snipped was only to simulate a browser screen resize event). I could have JS listening to the browser resize and observing the width, but that means more trouble down the road. Thus, if possible, a pure CSS implementation is preferred.

Comment: Added pure CSS solutions. For future reference, it would be helpful to declare stipulations in the question, instead of dismissing proposed answers after the fact  You did say in your question, *"the solution must by no means be limited to flex-box"*.

Comment: You're right; I should've been more explicit! Thank you for your detailed solution though! The grid-box approach looks exactly like what I was looking for *_*